# How to use sharedpreferences to save users roles and navigate to a specific page depending on role in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm working on app that have user logins (Admin login and user login). First i make a user part and it works, the account keep logged even when the app restart. and then when i have to separate the users (admin and user) i got some problem. I don't know how to code the shared preferences, this is the code when i make a user part

preference_helper.dart

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class PreferencesHelper {
  final Future<SharedPreferences> sharedPreferences;

  const PreferencesHelper({required this.sharedPreferences});

  static const String login = 'LOGIN';

  void setIsLogin(bool value) async {
    final prefs = await sharedPreferences;

    prefs.setBool(login, value);
  }

  Future<bool> get isLogin async {
    final prefs = await sharedPreferences;

    return prefs.getBool(login) ?? false;
  }
}
```

i use the provider like this

```
preference_notifier.dart
class PreferencesNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

  PreferencesNotifier({required this.preferencesHelper}) {
    _getIsLogin();
  }

  bool _isLogin = false;
  bool get isLogin => _isLogin;

  void _getIsLogin() async {
    _isLogin = await preferencesHelper.isLogin;
    notifyListeners();

    debugPrint(_isLogin ? 'isLogin true' : 'isLogin false');
  }

  void setIsLogin(bool value) async {
    preferencesHelper.setIsLogin(value);
    _getIsLogin();
  }
}
```

i want to use shared preferences to save the user roles and navigate to specific page. So if the user's log in it will go to the UserHomePage and if the admin log in it will go to the AdminHomePage. My backend is firebase firestore.

this is part of sign page (when click register button)

```
MaterialButton(
   color: primaryColor,
   textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
   height: 40,
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
   ),
   onPressed: () async {
      setState(() {
         _isLoading = true;
      });

   try {
      final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
      final email = _emailController.text;
      final password = _passwordController.text;
      const role = "user";

      await _auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
      )
      .then((value) => {postDetailsToFirestore(email, role)});

      navigator.pop();
   } catch (err) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(err.toString()));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
   } finally {
      setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  },
  child: const Text('Signup'),
),

postDetailsToFirestore(String email, String role) async {
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    var user = _auth.currentUser;
    CollectionReference ref = firebaseFirestore.collection('users');
    ref.doc(user!.uid).set({'email': _emailController.text, 'role': role});
  }
```

this is the login page (when click the login button)

```
MaterialButton(
    color: primaryColor,
    textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
    height: 40,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
 ),
 onPressed: () async {
    setState(() {
       _isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
       final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
       final email = _emailController.text;
       final password = _passwordController.text;

       await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
       );
       route();

       value.setIsLogin(true);

       navigator.pushReplacementNamed(HomePage.routeName);
    } catch (err) {
       final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(err.toString()));
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    } finally {
       setState(() {
           _isLoading = false;
       });
    }
 },
 child: const Text('Login'),
),
```

i want to navigate the navigator to specific user role

this is the route() function

```
void route() {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          if (documentSnapshot.get('role') == "user") {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, UserHomePage.routeName);
          } else {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, AdminHomePage.routeName);
          }
        } else {
          debugPrint('Document does not exist on the database');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

and this is the main.dart at runApp()

```
runApp(
    await preferencesHelper.isLogin
        ? const MyApp(
            pageRouteName: HomePage.routeName,
          )
        : const MyApp(
            pageRouteName: LoginPage.routeName,
          ),
  );
```

I really need to know how am i supposed to do because this is for my exam. I'm sorry if my english is bad, i'm barely use English to talk. Thank you

that code that i share is what i tried to make sharedpreferences but it just for 1 user, i dont know how to separate user (admin and user)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use architecture to separate the UI from logic and in your architect, you have to create a layer to handle basic requests of the local database and then create a class for implementing basic commands of the database, then you can create a separated storage layer for each of entities that you have.

the abstract basic commands class is like this :

```
abstract class LocalStorage {
 Future<void> write(final String key, final dynamic json);
 dynamic read<S>(final String key);
 void remove(final String key);
 void removeAll();
}
```

and for implementation :

```
class StorageService implements LocalStorage {
   StorageService() {
  _init();
  }

   late GetStorage storage;

   void _init() {
    storage = GetStorage();
   }

   @override
     Future<void> write(final String key, final dynamic value) async {
       await storage.write(key, convert.jsonEncode(value));
   }

   @override
     dynamic read<S>(final String key) {
       final value = storage.read(key);
       if (value == null) return;
       return convert.jsonDecode(value.toString());
   }


    @override
      void remove(final String key) {
      GetStorage().remove(key);
   }

    @override
     void removeAll() {
     GetStorage.Remove(key1);
     GetStorage.Remove(key2);
     ...
     
   }


 }
```

and for Usage for each entity:

```
class UserStorage {

     final LocalStorage _storage;

 Future<void> SaveUser(User usr) async {
   await _storage.write(userKey, usr);
  }
}
```

I have used GetX to handle local storage for read and write but you can replace your preferred shared preference library.